# Неправильно работает отрисовка меша из класса модели

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Пытаюсь сделать для себя класс для хранения и обрисовки 3д моделей но вот проблема. Загружаю кубик всё в порядке, загружаю ещё плоскость и отрисовую вместо неё отрисовуеться куб. Отключаю загрузку куба плоскость плоскость рисует в чём я ошибся?

```
class MeshT
{
public: 
    std::vector<int>vec1;
    int InS;
    int VerS;
    bool IStexture; //Чи має mesh текстуру
    GLuint texture; //Текстура
    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;  //створитии змінні для буферів
    string Log;
    MeshT(std::string urlV,std::string urlI)
    {
        IStexture = false;
    //====Просто считую всі цифри які є============ВЕРШИНИ
    GLfloat* a;
    int av;
    {
        std::vector<float>t;
        ifstream f(urlV.c_str());
        if(!f) {Log+="Error loading "; Log+=urlV.c_str(); Log+='\n'; return;}
        while (!f.eof()) {
          float n;
          f >> n;
          t.push_back(n);
        }
        f.close();
        a = new GLfloat[t.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while(i<t.size()) {a[i] = t[i]; i++;}
        av = t.size();
    }



    //====Просто считую всі цифри які є============ІНДЕКСИ
    int inv = 0;
    GLint* in;
    if(urlI.size() != 0)
    {
        {
            std::vector<GLint>t;
            ifstream f(urlI.c_str());
            if(!f) {Log+="Error loading "; Log+=urlI.c_str(); Log+='\n'; return;}
            while (!f.eof()) {
              GLint n;
              f >> n;
              t.push_back(n);
            }
            f.close();
            in = new GLint[t.size()];
            int i = 0;
            while(i<t.size()) {in[i] = t[i]; i++;}
            inv = t.size();
        }
    }








    InS = inv;
    VerS = av;

    //=================Якщо індекси присутні=================
    if(InS != 0)
    {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); //Згенерувати буфер
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); //зв'язую наш буфер з Open GL
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat) * av, a, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  //Передати дані на відеокарту

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint)*inv, in, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,//Номер для шейдера
        3,//Розмір в одиницях
        GL_FLOAT, //Float
        GL_FALSE, //Нормалізація
        8*sizeof(float), //Крок
        (GLvoid*)0 //Змішення в буфері
        );

     glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,//Номер для шейдера
        3,//Розмір в одиницях
        GL_FLOAT, //Float
        GL_FALSE, //Нормалізація
        8*sizeof(float), //Крок
        (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(float)) //Змішення в буфері
        );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


        glVertexAttribPointer(
        2,//Номер для шейдера
        2,//Розмір в одиницях
        GL_FLOAT, //Float
        GL_FALSE, //Нормалізація
        8*sizeof(float), //Крок
        (GLvoid*)(6*sizeof(float)) //Змішення в буфері
        );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);



    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs), remember: do NOT unbind the EBO, keep it bound to this VAO
    }
    else
    {

        {
             //GLfloat* vertices,int vs,GLint* indices,int is   
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); //Згенерувати буфер


        // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); //зв'язую наш буфер з Open GL
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat) * av, a, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  //Передати дані на відеокарту



           glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,//Номер для шейдера
        3,//Розмір в одиницях
        GL_FLOAT, //Float
        GL_FALSE, //Нормалізація
        8*sizeof(float), //Крок
        (GLvoid*)0 //Змішення в буфері
        );

     glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,//Номер для шейдера
        3,//Розмір в одиницях
        GL_FLOAT, //Float
        GL_FALSE, //Нормалізація
        8*sizeof(float), //Крок
        (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(float)) //Змішення в буфері
        );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


        glVertexAttribPointer(
        2,//Номер для шейдера
        2,//Розмір в одиницях
        GL_FLOAT, //Float
        GL_FALSE, //Нормалізація
        8*sizeof(float), //Крок
        (GLvoid*)(6*sizeof(float)) //Змішення в буфері
        );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);




        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

        glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs), remember: do NOT unbind the EBO, keep it bound to this VAO
        }

    }



    }


    void setTexture(GLuint t)
    {
        IStexture = true;
        texture = t;
    }

    void draw()
    {
        //IMEG
        if(IStexture)
        {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        }

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, InS, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);


        //glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }

    ~MeshT()
    {
        // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    }
};
```

загрузка

```
ShaderL test("data\\shaders\\all\\test.vs","data\\shaders\\all\\test.frag");

    MeshT CUB("data\\mesh\\Cube.vertex","data\\mesh\\Cube.index");
CUB.setTexture(LoTe("data\\texture\\1.jpg"));
cout<<"CUB: "<<CUB.Log<<endl;


MeshT plane("data\\mesh\\plane.vertex","data\\mesh\\plane.index");
cout<<"PLANE: "<<plane.Log<<endl;
plane.setTexture(CUB.texture);
```

Прорисовка

```
caM(camera,test.shaderProgram,Wi,Hei);

    //========================(4)
        {
                    TransformU Tra1;
                    Tra1.translate(0,0,0);
                    Tra1.rotate(0,timer,0);
                    CUB.draw();
                    Tra1.active("model",test.shaderProgram);
        }

        {
                    TransformU Tra1;
                    Tra1.translate(0,-3,0);
                    Tra1.scale(5);
                    plane.draw();
                    Tra1.active("model",test.shaderProgram);
        }
```

[Проект полностью 679КБ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BPpxtNL2qLE6obKAvBeuADQfnMFRPY7M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: У вас класс [нарушает the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Может в этот раз проблема и не в этом, но лучше уладить.

Comment: Добавь код использующий класс `MeshT` для загрузки кубика и плоскости. Ошибки: если `InS == 0` ты не создаешь `VBO` и `EBO`. Без `EBO` для отрисовки надо использовать `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BPpxtNL2qLE6obKAvBeuADQfnMFRPY7M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты передаешь матрицу модели в шейдер после отрисовки модели:

```
CUB.draw();
Tra1.active("model",test.shaderProgram);
```

Выходит куб рисуется с матрицей плоскости а плоскость с матрицей куба.

Comment: Спасибо понял, сначала нужно активировать а потом рисовать поменять строчки местами.